# Controlling 64 servo with arduino

Tags: arduino, power, servo, power-consumption

I want control 64 servo with arduino. I'm planning to use I2C based controller cards for control. I going to use `SG90` and `PCA9685`. According to datasheet each servo consuming **550mA**. Now I am going to choose a power supply. But which type of power supply is enough for me? Thanks

Comment: it depends how much work those servos are doing. 550mA is some characteristic number, but most probably not what your application will demand,  probably you should start by making some measurements

Comment: "According to datasheet each servo consuming 550mA." - according to my tests the _unloaded_ peak current draw of the SG90 is ~750mA. I hope you don't need to operate 64 of them at the same time!

Comment: Thanks for all reply. Sometimes i must be operate 45-50 of them.

Comment: At the minimum 4.8V that would be 0.55*4.8*64 = 169W

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to control 64 servos. You could use a desktop/laptop power supply in combination with a step-down converter. Be warned, however, because you are going to need a beefy converter and power supply rated for around 175 watts. A desktop power supply wouldn't be a problem, but a laptop power supply may not be powerful enough (Or you might need multiple laptop power bricks if that's all you have for some reason...). However, keep in mind that you will need this kind of power if you are going to be constantly moving the servos.

Comment: I think ı should use 5 volt but I couldnt decided to current